# Site wide navbar search using class based views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a search form in the navbar that is obviously available site wide, however, search only works on the home page because thats the view the search code is written.  I figured class based views were the answer such that I could easily add the search functionality as a mixin or something of the kind.

Bottomline: I'm having trouble abstracting the search functionality in a class based DRY

The search form returns www.site.com/?q=search.  I need to grab q from the GET request and return that info to my search.html page.

This is my code as it stands

views.py

```
class HomeListView(ListView, Searchmixin):
     model = Part
     queryset = Part.objects.order_by('-creDate')
     template_name = 'parts/index.html'
     paginate_by = 20
     is_paginated = True
```

search.py

```
class SearchMixin(object):
    def sindex(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return httpResponse(query)


    def perf(self, query):
        if query is not None:
                pollist = self.objects.filter(
                                  Q(project__name__icontains=query) |
                                  Q(owner__icontains=query) |
                                  Q(description__icontains=query) |
                                  Q(pnumber__icontains=query)
                                          )

        return render(request, 'parts/search.html', pollist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice job creating your first site. On every view that you would like to have a functional search bar, you should include the `SearchMixin` that you've created.

One important thing that will save you some trouble down the road is to make sure that the generic class-based views go on the right-hand side of any mixins that you've created -- i.e. `class HomeListView(Searchmixin, ListView)`. That's because Python has an order in which it builds up the class based on what it's inheriting from. Sometimes there could be conflicts if the default ones get overwritten before they're supposed to.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that.  My problem is also that the presented code is flawed in some way that I cannot seem to decipher.  Sorry I should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SearchMixin` and inheriting everywhere, I suggest creating a `SearchView`, assigning it some URL and returning search results from there.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'/search/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
    ...
]

# views.py
class SearchView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 20  # to show 20 search results per page

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['parts/search.html']

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        pollist = YourModel.objects.all()
        if query:
            pollist = pollist.filter(
                Q(project__name__icontains=query) |
                Q(owner__icontains=query) |
                Q(description__icontains=query) |
                Q(pnumber__icontains=query)
            )
        return pollist
```

Now in your JavaScript, you can perform asynchronous `GET` request to http://www.your_site.com/search/?q=some_search_term, and fetch results and append them in DOM. Hope this helps.